Mi dropdown abre pero no cierra mediante el botón de bootstrap Angular14
Anteriormente había hecho una pregunta en la que los estilos de bootstrap funcionaban pero el js no, como el caso básico de un botón. Me contestaron que probara con /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Tal que ahora el json queda así
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
        ]

Para cerrarlo tengo que clicar fuera, si vuelvo a clicar en el botón no se cierra, pero si si clico fuera, lo que pasa es que mi página es responsive y cuando paso a formato teléfono, el menú que se convierte a un dropdown desplegable al clicarlo se abre, pero volviendole a dar no se cierra y se queda abierto, en este caso clicar fuera no funciona.
Tiene que ser algo de configuración porque eso me pasa en un botón, en un dropdown tal cual de la documentación...
Mis versiones son:
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
"jquery": "^3.7.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",


Usa la versión de bootstrap adaptada para Angular https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home
